# How can I get the Pinterest API to accept my redirect URL?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, pinterest

I am trying to build an app in node.js that connects to Pinterest via its API. I can get an access token via Postman and test my app in single-user mode, but I am unable to incorporate OAuth2 to test my app for a second user. Every configuration of my code and settings at developer.pinterest.com yields the error "The provided redirect_uri ... does not match any of my registered redirect URIs."

I registered what I believe are correct callback URLs at developers.pinterest.com--many variants, with and without trailing slashes. My callback is hosted via https.

I tried calling Pinterest's auth URLs OAuth2 in my server code (node.js), and via browser address bar.

https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://www.outfinterest.com/auth/pinterest/callback/&client_id=5042375080944909391&scope=read_public&state=true

I attempted the auth from a browser logged into Pinterest as me, and from a browser logged in as a registered tester of my app.

What must I do to get Pinterest to accept my callback URL?

Do I need to submit my app for approval before I can authorize via OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by reducing the set URLs registered at developer.pinterest.com to just the one I need, then reloaded the page with the app settings.